# Redirecting to default page after applying 'routerLink' and target as _blank

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working in Angular 2. My typeScript version is 2.3.
My issue is that after applying target as _blank, it is being redirected to default page & not to which it is being redirected.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Student's view" [routerLink]="['/app/quotationsview/e1574258']" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

Here is my tsconfig file:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "types": [],
    "lib": [
      "es5",
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
}
```

This issue occurs only after dist is build & it works fine on ng serve.

Comment: show your routing file code here

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/drs1ebzv/

Comment: still you missed `AdminModule` routing file

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/s46ct8kv/

Comment: there is no route added for the path `quotationsview` that's why your app is redirecting to default page

Comment: But why it doesn't occur in local system & if I builds dist only then I'm encountered with this issue.

Comment: even that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a title="Student's view" [routerLink]="['/app/quotationsview/e1574258']" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

Remove `href=""`

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pe9l5a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: adding ` href="javascript:void(0);"` to your code is also working so problem is not in `href=""`

Answer (score 0):

### Replace with this one

```
<a routerLink="/app/quotationsview/e1574258"></a>
```